# Cannot load class object into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I try to find all objects of class .galleryImage in my .html file everything works fine, but when I want to put it into script.js I always read 0 elements in variable images.

```
 <div id="gallery"></div>
 <script>
 $(function(){
   for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
     var name = 'picture' + i + '.jpg';
     var img =$('<img class="galleryImage" src="picture/'+name+'"/>');
     $('#gallery').append(img);
   }
   var images = $('#gallery').find('.galleryImage');
  console.log(images);
 });
   var g= new PS.Gallery('gallery');
 </script>
```

And the function

```js
(function (ns){
 ns.Gallery = function(id){
  var gallery=$('#' + id);
  console.log(gallery);
  var images = gallery.find('.galleryImage');
  console.log(images);
  images.each(function(idx,el){
  console.log('are u here?');
});
}
}(window.PS = window.PS || {}));
```

Comment: Not clear which part is causing problems. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @kubauser can you provide jsfiddle or codepen??

Comment: Did you put ```<script src="script.js"></script>``` at the top of the html page, or at the bottom?

Comment: What made it work...Please let us know and consider accepting the answer if it is of any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get error at this step

var g= new PS.Gallery('gallery');

change your js code sequence to this

```
  (function (ns){
        ns.Gallery = function(id){
            var gallery=$('#' + id);
            console.log(gallery);
            var images = gallery.find('.galleryImage');
            console.log(images);
            images.each(function(idx,el){
                console.log('are u here?');
            });
        }
    }(window.PS = window.PS || {}));
    $(function(){
        for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
            var name = 'picture' + i + '.jpg';
            var img =$('<img class="galleryImage" src="picture/'+name+'"/>');
            $('#gallery').append(img);
        }
        var images = $('#gallery').find('.galleryImage');
        console.log(images);
    });

        var g= new PS.Gallery('gallery');
```

PS:check the snippet

```js
 (function (ns){
        ns.Gallery = function(id){
            var gallery=$('#' + id);
           // console.log(gallery);
            var images = gallery.find('.galleryImage');
           // console.log(images);
            images.each(function(idx,el){
                //console.log('are u here?');
            });
        }
    }(window.PS = window.PS || {}));
    $(function(){
        for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
            var name = 'picture' + i + '.jpg';
            var img =$('<img class="galleryImage" src="picture/'+name+'"/>');
            $('#gallery').append(img);
        }
        var images = $('#gallery').find('.galleryImage');
        console.log(images.length);

    });
    var g= new PS.Gallery('gallery');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

After this change everything would work as expected. This is because function hoisting :**a function declaration doesn't just hoist the function's name. It also hoists the actual function definition.**

Hope this helps